# IntelliJ IDEA won't load Groovy found on my disk

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, groovy, ide

Hi I lately wanted to start developing in Groovy but when I try IntelliJ IDEA it won't load Groovy cause it says:

> Looks like Groovy distribution in specified path is broken. Cannot
>   determine version.

Whats going on I even tried some older release and it didn't work either :( Did someone have same problem or knows how to work that out?

Comment: Is this 2.4.10? I've seen that as well... Try 2.4.9

Comment: yea I tried 2.4.9 and 2.4 and none worked

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: it is latest 2017.1 i think

Comment: You are affected by https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170022. If it's not 2.4.10 then please file another issue describing steps to reproduce.

Comment: I just had to rename it from 2.4.10 to 2.4.1 and it found it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue:

- [IDEA-170022](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170022) Cannot create Groovy project, because cannot create Groovy library (2.4.10 version)

As a workaround you can use Groovy 2.4.9 or rename `groovy-2.4.10.jar` to `groovy-2.4.9.jar`.

The problem is fixed for IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.1 and 2016.3.6 versions.

Comment: hope it is going to be so.

Comment: I am using 2017.1.1 and the problem is still there.

Comment: Are you sure about 2017.1.1? Show About screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Ive changed groovy-x.x.x.jar to groovy.jar and it works in IntelliJ 2016.1.2

Answer (score 2):

Changing groovy-x.x.x.jar to groovy.jar solved my issue as well, I am using Intellij Idea 2017.2.2 with Groovy SDK groovy-2.5.0-beta-1

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can search for similar questions, or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question, and include a link to this one to help provide context. See https://stackoverflow.com/tour: Ask questions, get answers, no distractions

Comment: actually it did answer my question, I had the exact same problem with IntelliJ ULTIMATE 2017.3, which means the real answer is : "IntelliJ (still) has an issue, you must rename the jar to be able to load it"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an issue with the IntelliJ! This works by changing the jar. Thanks for sharing this. Just adding more bits.

Just in case, the jar is in the lib folder. I've downloaded the groovy-2.4.13 and rename the jar from /groovy-2.4.13/lib/groovy.2.4.13 to /groovy-2.4.13/lib/groovy