# Failed to create Library in intelliji when configuring groovy sdk

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

Intelliji Version: 2017.1
Groovy version : 2.4.10 (zip file from official website)

Got following error in intelliji when configuring groovy library.

[image]

Comment: It's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/43041188/104891.

Comment: I think it's somehow duplicated, the difference is I was using 2017.1 which was declared to be resolved.

Comment: No, it's stated that the issue is resolved in 2017.1.1.

Comment: It doesn't as I mentioned, I encountered this problem in Mac with intelliji 2017.1

Comment: 2017.1.1 is available at https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2017.1+EAP, you are probably using 2017.1 and not 2017.1.1.

Comment: 2017.1.1 != 2017.1, 2017.1.1 > 2017.1

Answer (score 0):

switched to 2.4.8 solved my problem, seems like intelliji doesn't support the latest version of groovy